# Save and get the session or cookie with Nodejs and Express not working

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, client-server

I'm pretty new using NodeJs and Express. I'm trying to save a session or a cookie with the user when you log in, and then get it in some other calls. What I'm doing:

server.js: Where I declare the library and create the session.

```
const session = require('client-sessions');

app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'JLB_SECRET',
  secure: false,
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));
```

login.js: Where the user logs in, here the cookie or session is saved well.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('hacemos login', req.session);
  var users = req.body;
  if (!users.pass || !users.email) {
    res.status(400);
    return res.json({
      status: 400,
      error: 'Bad data'
    });
  }
  User.findOne({
    email: users.email,
    pass: users.pass
  }, function(err, userFound) {
    if (err || userFound === null) {
      res.status(404);
      return res.json({
        status: 404,
        error: 'User not found'
      });
    } else {
      const userToSend = userDto.serviceToDto(userFound);
      req.session.user = userToSend; // here is saved properly
      console.log('pasamos la session', req.session.user);
      return res.json({
        user: userToSend,
        token: createToken(userFound)
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Competences.js: I try to get the session in another call, but it's always empty.

```
router.get('/competence/user/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('veamos la sesion', req.session); //HERE IS ALWAYS EMPTY
  Competence.find({
    "idUser":  mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)
  }, function(err, competences) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }
    const competenceToSend = competenceDto.serviceListToDto(competences);
    res.statusCode = 200;
    return res.json(competenceToSend);
  });
});
```

Does anybody what I'm doing wrong or how to do it?? Here is where I got the guide to do it: https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions

Regardssss and thank you!

Comment: As long as both `routers` are employed in same express `app`, this should work. Can you show the actual `log`

Comment: This is what I get when I log in:  pasamos la session { 
  idCoach: '596f121f9e8f276bf6e19ee7',
  rol: { user: true, coach: false, admin: false },
  company: [],
  area: 'el area',
  position: '',
  email: 'user11',
  personData: 
   { name: 'un user a sssssssaco',
     surname: 'y su apellido',
     birthDate: '15-09-2017' },
  createdAt: 2017-09-15T06:18:49.710Z,
  id: 59bb70c94b4a0b7df1384358 }

and this is what I get when I try to get it again: veamos la sesion {}

Comment: What are you using to test it, a browser, postman or curl ?

Comment: I'm using a browser